# call IKsTopologyInfo::CreateNodeInstance from vidcap.h in Delphi

Tags: delphi, api, video-capture

I'm writing a tiny app managing webcam in Delphi. I have working sample piece of code in C++, and i need to rewrite it in Delphi as a part of my app. All works fine in Delphi, except single method call, which crashes with "Access violation at address 63252469 in module 'vidcap.ax'. Write of address 11D206FD" message.

Here is a part of C++ sample code which works (without errors handling):

```
#include <vidcap.h>         // For IKsTopologyInfo  
#include <ksproxy.h>        // For IKsControl  
....  
//pKsTopologyInfo is passed from the outside
IKsControl *pKsControl = NULL;  
DWORD dwNumNodes = 0;  
pKsTopologyInfo->get_NumNodes(&dwNumNodes);  
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < dwNumNodes; i++)  
{  
  pKsTopologyInfo->get_NodeType(i, &guidNodeType);  
  if(IsEqualGUID(guidNodeType, KSNODETYPE_DEV_SPECIFIC))  
  {  
    hr = pKsTopologyInfo->CreateNodeInstance(i, IID_IKsControl, (void **)&pKsControl);
```

And here is a corresponding part of my code in Delphi:

```
//KsTopologyInfo is IKsTopologyInfo passed from the outside  
//pKsControl is ^IKsControl, which is taken from DirectShow9.pas from DSPack components set.
KsTopologyInfo.get_NumNodes(@dwNumNodes);  
for i:=0 to dwNumNodes-1 do  
begin  
  KsTopologyInfo.get_NodeType(i,@guidNodeType);  
  if IsEqualGUID(guidNodeType,KSNODETYPE_DEV_SPECIFIC) then  
  begin  
    KsTopologyInfo.CreateNodeInstance(i,IID_IKsControl,@pKsControl);
```

The error occurs in the Delphi code at the last line here, while in the C++ it works fine.
Inspection during step-by-step debugger does not show any differences - both in Delphi and C++ it gets 11 for dwNumNodes, then IsEqualGUID returns TRUE when i==3 and guidNodeType=={941C7AC0-C559-11D0-8A2B-00A0C9255AC1}. So in both cases it calls CreateNodeInstance with the same values i=3 and IID_IKsControl={28F54685-06FD-11D2-B27A-00A0C9223196}

To my pity, i couldn't find vidcap.h transformed to Delphi .pas file, so i written my own description for IKsTopologyInfo, and i suppose that i have error in CreateNodeInstance method description. Here it is from vidcap.h:

```
virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE CreateNodeInstance(  
  /* [in] */ DWORD dwNodeId,  
  /* [in] */ REFIID iid,  
  /* [out] */ void **ppvObject) = 0;
```

And here is my variant for Delphi:

```
function CreateNodeInstance(dwNodeId:DWord; iid:TGuid; p:Pointer):HRESULT; stdcall;
```

I tried a lot of variants with the third parameter - var Obj, Pointer, PPointer (which is ^Pointer), and also tried to pass different variants values to it (IKsControl, ^IKsControl, ^(^IKsControl), Pointer, ^Pointer - and none of them work. In any case i got the same error.

Need any advice on how make it working, and how should look correct IKsTopologyInfo.CreateNodeInstance description and call in Delphi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to MSDN [definition of **REFIID**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc237816%28v=prot.13%29.aspx):

```
typedef GUID IID;
typedef IID* REFIID;
```

So `REFIID` is a pointer to a `GUID` and should be translated as `PGUID` or, as `iid` is an input parameter and seems to be mandatory, can also be passed as a `const` `TGUID`.

Also, MSDN states that in [CreateNodeInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd390149%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> *ppvObject* receives a pointer to the requested interface on the node object. **The caller must release the interface**.

So the third parameter should be declared as a pointer to an interface in order to allow Delphi to manage it. Declaring it as a `var` `IUnknown` or, as it is an output parameter, as an `out` `IUnknown` forces the parameter to be a variable of type `IUnknown` and therefore that must be casted to the real interface type for using it.

The C++ declaration

```
virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE CreateNodeInstance(  
  /* [in] */ DWORD dwNodeId,  
  /* [in] */ REFIID iid,  
  /* [out] */ void **ppvObject) = 0;
```

becomes

```
function CreateNodeInstance(dwNodeId: DWord; const iid: TGUID; ppvObject: PUnknown): HRESULT; stdcall;
```

And can be called as follows:

```
var
  KsControl: IKsControl;

KsTopologyInfo.CreateNodeInstance(i, IID_IKsControl, @KsControl);
```

Comment: Works Great! Thanks. Seems the real problem was that i didn't notice that iid is REFIID, and tried to pass just TGUID, and not as const also.